# How do I create an array that prompts the user to enter the name of taco 1 & then price 1?

Tags: java, arrays

With the code I currently have, the user is able to enter one taco at a time, but when I run it, I'll enter the name of the first taco, and then prices automatically list *"Enter Taco's Price"* 1 through 10. How can this be fixed. I'm confident I am doing something wrong when it comes to the loop.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TacoSort {
    //Create a constant amount of temperatures
    public static int NUMBER_OF_TACOS = 10;
    public static int NUMBER_OF_PRICES = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the taco price sorter! Enter 10 taco names and prices and I'll sort it!");

        //Populates array of 10 tacos
        //Prompts user to enter name of each taco
        String[] tacos = new String[NUMBER_OF_TACOS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS+1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i+1) + "\n");
            tacos[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Populates array of 10 prices
        //Prompts user to enter price of each taco
        double[] prices = new double[NUMBER_OF_PRICES];
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; j++)

            System.out.print("Enter taco's price" + (j+1) + "\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

User output should resemble:

> Enter the name of taco 1
>   Crunchy Taco
>   Enter taco's price
>   1.19
>   Enter the name of taco 2
>   Crunchy Taco Supreme
>   Enter taco's price
>   1.59
>   Enter the name of taco 3
>   Soft Taco
>   Enter taco's price
>   1.19

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about tacos (just kidding, I really do), but there are a few things done wrong here that I notice.

First off, your for-loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++)
```

You originally had `i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS + 1`, this would result in an index out of bounds exception.

Second, you don't terminate the brackets for your first for-loop correctly; you're missing a curly-brace. You're also missing a starting curly-brace after your second for-loop condition.

Third, you should probably be checking for erroneous user input by looping until the user enters in an appropriate value, and using type conversions instead of `Scanner#nextDouble()`.

Finally, you're doing the entire first loop, then the entire second loop. You should be asking for name and price for each taco within the same loop, if you expect your program to ask for name and price for Taco #1, followed by name and price for Taco #2, and so on.

Correct code would look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TacoSort {
    //Create a constant amount of tacos
    public static int NUMBER_OF_TACOS = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the taco price sorter! Enter 10 taco names and prices and I'll sort it!");

        //Populates array of 10 tacos
        //Prompts user to enter name of each taco
        String[] tacos = new String[NUMBER_OF_TACOS];
        double[] prices = new double[NUMBER_OF_TACOS]; // NOTE Moved this up from below
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++) // NOTE Fixed off-by-one error
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i+1) + "\n");
            tacos[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter taco's price " + (i+1) + "\n");
            prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble(); // TODO Fix this so it checks for non-double input?
        } // NOTE Added end-bracket here!

        // Consolidated prices loop into taco names loop

        // Do something with the list of tacos and prices
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentations and braces are out of sync.

You likely want an end-brace after the line `tacos[i] = keyboard.nextLine();`

You likely want a start-brace after the line `for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; j++)`.

But that still won't ask the questions in the sequence you requested.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the ordering of your loop. Also, you have numerous exceptions and syntax errors.

As it stands, you want a single loop, since the arrays are of the same length. Yours will ask for Taco 1, Price 1-10, then Taco 2, Price 1-10, etc.

Ditch the nested loop and you'll be fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++) //tacos +1 will go out of bounds! 
{
    System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i+1) + "\n");
    tacos[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Populates array of 10 prices
    //Prompts user to enter price of each taco
    System.out.print("Enter taco's price" + (i+1) + "\n");
    System.out.println("\n");
    prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in logic of above code. Please look into this, it is working perfectly

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TacoSort 
{
    //Create a constant amount of temperatures
    public static int NUMBER_OF_TACOS = 10;
    public static int NUMBER_OF_PRICES = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the taco price sorter! Enter 10 taco names and prices and I'll sort it!");

        //Populates array of 10 tacos
        //Prompts user to enter name of each taco

        String[] tacos = new String[NUMBER_OF_TACOS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TACOS; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of taco " + (i+1) + "\n");
            tacos[i] = keyboard.next();

            //Populates array of 10 prices
            //Prompts user to enter price of each taco
            double[] prices = new double[NUMBER_OF_PRICES];
            //for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_PRICES; j++) //

            System.out.print("Enter taco's price" + (i+1) + "\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```